# Deploy local deep learning web app to web

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, gpu, consumerweb

So I've built a (relatively) simple web app with a deep learning image classifier, and I have it running on localhost. How do I upload this to the web so that I can link to it from my website? The usage will not be very high at all, but the model needs GPU so it would be better if it's a pay/hour used or something similar. What are the best services to use to do this (as cheap as possible)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To host the Deep Learning Model to a web-app you can use:
-Flask 
-Tensorflow-js

I guess you can use GPU on both Flask and Tensorflow-js